# Swift 5: Error in success/failure block "'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block"

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, try-catch, catch-block

I am writing a closure with error handling, but I am getting a warning "'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block" in the catch line.
This is my code:

```
class Service {
func graphQL(body: [String:Any], onSuccess: @escaping (Foundation.Data) -> (), onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            onFailure(error)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do{
                onSuccess(data)
            }
            catch{
                onFailure(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}


class TimeDepositManager {
func getTimeDeposits(onSuccess: @escaping ([TimeDeposits]) -> (), onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
    let body = ["query": "{ account { timeDeposits { returnAmount interestRate dueDate originalAmount id startDate currency } } }"
    ]

    Service().graphQL(body: body, onSuccess: { data in
        let json = try? JSONDecoder().decode(GraphQLResponse.self, from: data)
        onSuccess(json?.data?.account?.timeDeposits ?? [])
    }, onFailure: { error in
        print(error)
    })
}
```

I want the logic of onSuccess in the func getTimeDeposits(), but how remove this catch block warning?

Comment: Remove the do/catch to remove the warning because you can only use that when you have a function that is declared to throw, you want an if/else instead.

Comment: Not related to your question but looks like you have created a custom struct and named it `Data`. You should choose another name for your structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift requires some "expectations" when it comes to error handling.

That is, `success` needs to declare that it can `throw` an error (based on my understand of your requirements), for example

```
func graphQL(body: [String:Any], onSuccess: @escaping (Foundation.Data) throws -> (), onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> ()) {
```

And then you will need to `try` and call `success`...

```
do{
    try onSuccess(data)
}
catch{
    onFailure(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> how remove this catch block warning?

By *removing* the `do-catch` block entirely because there is nothing which `throws`

Replace

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            onFailure(error)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do{
                onSuccess(data)
            }
            catch{
                onFailure(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
```

with

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, _, error) in
        if let error = error {
            onFailure(error)
        } else {
            onSuccess(data!)
        }
    }.resume()
```

Side note: Rather than very cumbersome and dated

```
onSuccess: @escaping (Foundation.Data) -> (), onFailure: @escaping (Error) -> ())
```

consider to use the `Result` type

```
completion: @escaping (Result<Data,Error>) -> Void)
```